# How does function invocation work in JavaScript as an value to part of an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, datatable, datatables

I'm working with datatables.js library. The contents of the code isn't what I'm trying to understand, but how functions work as arguments/parameters. Why doesn't the last version work, whereas the first two do? I understand that the first two are essentially the same thing, but what about javascript prevents me from do the last option below?

```js
function GetDateTime(value){
    if (value == null) return "";
    var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/; //date format from server side
    var results = pattern.exec(value);
    var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));
    var tMonth = dt.getMonth() + 1;
    var tDay = dt.getDate();
    
    return (tMonth.toString().length > 1 ? tMonth : "0" + tMonth) + "/" + (tDay.toString().length > 1 ? tDay : "0" + tDay) + "/" + dt.getFullYear();
} // function GetDateTime



...
// This works
{
    "data": "Date",
    "autoWidth": true,
    "render": function (value) {
        return GetDateTime(value);
    }    
}
...
// This works
{
    "data": "Date",
    "autoWidth": true,
    "render": function (value) {
        // The exact same code in GetDateTime(value)
    }    
}
... 
// This does not work
{
    "data": "Date",
    "autoWidth": true,
    "render": GetDateTime(value)
    }    
}
```

As far as I'm aware, the last one is doing the exact same thing, however when I do that, it throws an error saying "value is undefined." How is value any more defined than with the anonymous function declaration? What about that causes javascript to pass a value in there as opposed to inside an implicit function call?

Comment: The last one does NOT do the same thing. The first two assign a function to the property named `render` - the last one assigns the return value of the function call - a string. So when dataTables attempts to call the function that is referred to by `render`, it fails since there is no function there to call.

Comment: `value is undefined` because dataTables calls the `render` function and passes the value to the function _at that time_. As stated above, you are invoking the function immediately as the assignment - at _that_ time, `value` is not defined.

Comment: @RandyCasburn That makes total sense so thank you for clarifying that for me! I found out what I "really" wanted was to pass "GetDateTime," the function, instead of invoking it at the time of assigning it to the property.

Answer (score 2):

This would work because it passes the value of the property to your function:

```js
{
    "data": "Date",
    "autoWidth": true,
    "render": value => GetDateTime(value)
}
```